# Trim mode. "Crop Keep position" in texturepacker doesn't work in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I cannot figure out how it works. But as I understand the trim mode in Texturepacker: "Crop Keep position" should work this way:
"All the transparent background is removed and the information about the position of the colored area within the original sprite is saved in the plist file"
As I load the plist file in COCOS2d, the position of the colored area is remembered and if I do in cocos2d:

```
sprite.setPosition(new cc.p(0,0));
```

the sprite position will be relative to the original transparent area and not the colored area ? Is this right. So if I will load a sprite with at the left side 20px of transparent area a setPosition to X = 0 will put the sprite 20px far from the left border, so ? Well it do not work for me, and in cocos2d the trasparent area is not considered.

I'm loading the spritesheets this way:

```
var cache = cc.SpriteFrameCache.getInstance();
cache.addSpriteFrames("spritesheet.plist", "srcSprites/spritesheet.png");

this.sprite = cc.Sprite.createWithSpriteFrameName("00.png");
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a sprite's texture is centered on the position. So crop position will not have any visible effect compared to a trimmed sprite unless you change the anchorPoint.

The only difference between trim and crop (keep pos) is that the contentSize of the texture changes, but the texture's position relative to the sprite position remains the same.

The crop (flush pos) should do what you're experiencing, ie the trimmed size is no longer considered as part of the texture's contentSize.

Note also that TP mentions the crop features are not supported by all frameworks. I don't know whether cocos2d supports that feature, it actually might not. It's not normally needed by cocos2d anyway because trimming suffices.

Comment: I used the trim mode. It was sufficient for my purposes. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same situation, but I had similar situation and found out combination of TexturePacker options.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/42351?r=42435